# Is it possible to add a global navigation bar to my sites?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, my-site, global-navigation

Is it possible to add a global navigation bar to my sites for SharePoint 2016?

I've tried enabling publishing features on the my site host but it did not work.